# Excel Formula for converting elapsed hh.mm time in a cell to hh.hundredths in the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column E, I place elapsed time in the format of hh.mm.  Note the period separator and not a colon.  I am needing to retain everything from the period to the left, but convert the minutes into hundredths of an hour for time tracking, and retain the result in the same cell.

I have an excel sheet that maps every minute of the hour to the corresponding hundredth equivalent, so some sort of lookup could be performed, or a formula to calculate from scratch could be used.  I know that the formula `=("hh:mm"*24)` will convert hours/minutes into hours/hundredths, but I am having trouble translating that to my usage case.  I could possibly use the `RIGHT` function to get my minutes and convert them, but how would I maintain everything from the period left whether it is one hour digit or two?

Comment: If column E is a time that is formatted as `hh.mm` then `E2*24` should work. Make sure that the cell is formatted as general as it will change it to a decimal.

Comment: Column E is formatted as a number.  So, for example, if I work a total of 1 hour and 53 minutes on something I would enter 1.53 into, for example, `E2`, and `E2` would then be changed to 1.88.

Comment: You would need vba to change the value of the cell that is being tested.  A formula will not do that.  It would cause a circular reference.  So do what @Grade'Eh'Bacon suggests.  Also how would you know what was being entered was truly a time reference and the user did not do the math in their head.  It is pretty easy to change 1.15 to 1.25 in my head.

Comment: I do all entry on the sheet so I can ensure the numbers are hours/minutes, and you are correct, for certain time intervals (e.g., every 5, 10, 15, 20, 30 minutes) the calculation is simple. The issue is tracking to one minute intervals without needlessly spending time on calculating time mentally. Unfortunately two columns is not an option because of the software that I must import the spreadsheet into, so I will look into the VBA option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty Worksheet event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("E:E"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Target = Int(Target) + (Target - Int(Target)) * 100 / 60
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Put it in the worksheet code for the worksheet you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick code, Scott! I dropped this in the worksheet's code sheet, and when I enter a value into a cell in 'E' it acts as if it is calculating, but the code is not affecting the value in the cell.  As my test value I was putting in 1.15.

Comment: @rkent Hmm.  It is in column E correct?  Right now the code is only for column E.

Comment: @rkent did you get it to work? If so, click on the green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will mark this question as being answered.

Comment: Interestingly, I was able to make it work this morning after saving a copy of the workbook under a different name, restarting Excel, and then working in the new copy of the workbook. It still does not work in the old workbook. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use multiple cells here - the original cell with data as formatted currently, and a new cell formatted as you describe. To do otherwise (ie: to rewrite over the same cell with the data) would require VBA unnecessarily complex for something of this nature.

Assuming your current data is in column A, put this in A1 and drag down:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1))+VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))/60
```

What this does is take the leftmost characters in A1, up to the point where "." exists, and adds in the rightmost characters in A1, starting from where "." exists to the end of A1. The rightmost characters have been / 60 to move to a decimal based system.